# После выбора вариантов заказа пропадает кнопка "добавить в корзину" woocommerce

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Столкнулся с проблемой работы вариативных товаров. Указал атрибуты, добавил вариации, указал для каждой цену. В файлах header и footer прописаны wp_head и wp_footer. При выборе атрибутов, пишет конечную цену и пропадает кнопка "добавить в корзину".
С простыми товарами проблем нет. Всё работает хорошо.
Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос добавлением в файл основного стиля style.css следующего кода:

```
.woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart .variations_button .woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-enabled {
    display: block !important;
}
```